# Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an SQLite db. This is the table below. It's getting added.

```
public boolean addAllCampaign(Allcampaigndata allcampaigndata) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
  contentValues.put(ALLCAMP_ID, allcampaigndata.getAllCampid());
  contentValues.put(ALLCAMP_NAME, allcampaigndata.getAllCampName());
  contentValues.put(ALLVIEWS, allcampaigndata.getAllViews());
  contentValues.put(ALLDESTROY, allcampaigndata.getAllDestroy());
  contentValues.put(ALLENDOFCAMP,allcampaigndata.getAllEndofcamp());
  db.insert(TABLE_NAME_EIGHT, null, contentValues);
  db.close();
  return true;
}
```

Now I have a method which has a query:

```
public Cursor getoneCampaign(int allcampaignid) {
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
  String sqleight =  "SELECT   * FROM  Allcampaigndata WHERE  allcampaid =?";
  Cursor d= db.rawQuery(sqleight, null);
  return d;
}
```

I am calling this method from here:

```
private void shownextcamp(int allcampaignid){
  Cursor d =db.getoneCampaign(allcampaignid);
  newcamid=d.getString(0);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Newcampid :"+newcamid,LENGTH_LONG).show();
  d.moveToFirst();
}
```

I am getting the below error. Just cannot figure out why:

> Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1
>   requested, with a size of 0

Comment: Which is the line where you get the error?

Comment: This line Lajos
newcamid=d.getString(0);

Comment: You aren't moving the cursor to the first row. Therefore, you're still pointed on row **-1**.

Comment: @Rotwang My sqlite query is select * from where campaid= something..So i gues it will only contain one record...

Comment: But if you never set the cursor on the first (and in your case only) record, your cursor will remain set before any record. Which causes... `Index -1 requested`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential issues with your code.

One is that a newly created cursor is positioned BEFORE any rows (position -1). So without moving the cursor to a row you are trying to access a non-existent row. The second is that if there are no rows returned from the query then again there would be no rows. The first of these was the cause of the error (index -1 with a size of 0).

You could code :-

```
private void shownextcamp(int allcampaignid){
    Cursor d =db.getoneCampaign(allcampaignid);
    if (d.getCount > 0) {
        d.moveToFirst();
        newcamid=d.getString(0);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Newcampid :"+newcamid,LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //handle no row
        }
    }
```

This a) checks if there are any rows and if so b) moves to the first row (overcoming both issues).

or if you expect one or multiple rows then use to replace the if construct above (note no handling of 0 rows in this, but checking count via d.getCount() could be added) :-

```
while (d.moveToNext()) {
    newcamid=d.getString(0);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Newcampid :"+newcamid,LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

`moveToNext` will effectively return false if there are no rows and if at the BEFORE position will move to the first row any subsequent iterations will move to the next record, finishing the while loop when there are no more rows due to the effective false raised.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method:

```
private void shownextcamp(int allcampaignid){
        Cursor d =db.getoneCampaign(allcampaignid);
        if (null == d) {
            return;//return 0;
        }
        while (d.moveToNext()){
            for (int i = 0;i < d.getColumnCount();i++){
                String columnName = d.getColumnName(i);
                Toast.makeText(mContext.getApplicationContext()
                        ,columnName+"(Newcampid) :"+d.getString(d.getColumnIndex(columnName))
                        ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        d.close();
    }
```

> Android.database.cursorindexoutofboundsexception exception occurs in d.getString(0);

This line of code, need to add if (d.moveToFirst ()) {} This judgment

The `"SELECT   * FROM  Allcampaigndata WHERE  allcampaid =?"` parameter in `db.rawQuery(sqleight, null)` specifies that column information is to be returned, or null if all columns are returned, but this is less efficient